# Understanding the error in the in/out power measurement of a DC-DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, efficiency

I'm no expert in electronics but I only have basic knowledge of electronics and electricity.

With that said I found this video on YouTube of a DC-to-DC converter that apparently is showing more power coming out the output than the input and would like to be able to understand how this is even possible, or if it is even a possibility, a scam or just plain wrong.

From my understanding you can not get out more energy than what you put into a system because of the conservation of energy law, unless of course it is drawing in some sort of atmospheric energy from outside of the system, which wouldn't be too hard to believe since the earth can be considered a giant capacitor with the ground being negative and the ionosphere being positive. Just think lightning.

Anyways this guy makes it very clear where all the connections are located and shows underneath the table to show that there's nothing hidden or anything like that, and that he's not into hiding things.

There isn't much to the circuit as it appears fairly simple, it's just a DC-to-DC converter that is looped back to itself. He has 4 meters, 2 meters reading input current and voltage, and 2 meters reading output current and voltage.

He mentions that it is a DC-to-DC converter and it looks like a DC-to-DC converter. He also says that he doesn't have a connection on the output negative to the input negative because they are already internally connected and so there is no need for another connection that is the same.

However the positive output is connected to the input positive with a meter in between reading current going from the output and going back to the input of the power supply.

This current is abnormally high and I can not understand how or why it can be that high.

I mean we are talking about just .057A of current going into the DC-to-DC converter with almost an amp coming back out while the voltages are almost identical.

This makes absolutely no sense to me and would like to hear a good reason for why this should occur and why this guy's meters are reading an over 1000% efficiency.

He also mentions that he made sure all 4 meters were working properly by testing with a resistor and making sure they all matched with simple ohm's law calculations and they were all working properly and there was nothing wrong with them.

He also used analog meters in place of the digital meters, I assume to eliminate voltage spikes from collapsing magnetic fields that would maybe possibly skew the meter's readings.

The thing is I don't have a lot of knowledge of how DC-to-DC converters work but I do understand some of them do not use collapsing magnetic fields or step up transformers, but some of them use nothing but capacitors and diodes by connecting and disconnecting capacitors In series and parallel in order to boost the voltage. Correct me if I am wrong on that.

Why am I seeing this? I imagine if I built the circuit in an attempt to replicate it I would most likely see the same thing, but if I did, what I would really like to know is why is that output current so huge?

I seek a good explanation of what could be the cause of that and if there's been any other instance of these result and if so then why and how.

I'm not sure if you can include links to YouTube videos but here's the link going to that particular video:

https://youtu.be/_gIuB-f-VnU

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is complete rubbish!

Comment: Please do not close. Explaining why measurement can fail and how to properly mesure is an interesting topic.

Comment: What about the converter though? What if it's the type where there are no voltage spikes from collapsing fields? I see there are 4 capacitors there in which there is a possibility it may be boosting voltage by connecting two of them in series.

Comment: Google the [laws of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_thermodynamics) to understand that it is impossible. (There are many [alternative facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_facts), however. :-)

Comment: "shows underneath the table to show that there's nothing hidden or anything like that" - I smell SCAM!

Comment: *> Anyways this guy makes it very clear where all the connections are located and shows underneath the table to show that there's nothing hidden or anything like that, and that he's not into hiding things.*

Just as a magician shows there's nothing up his sleeve

Comment: I'm upvoting this question because answering it was quite amusing.

Comment: Its easy, repeat the experiment and see what results *you* get. Then believe your results before you believe the results from a youtube video.

Comment: I stopped reading at "over 1000% efficiency". Perhaps I should have stopped at "I found this video on YouTube".

Answer (score 5):

I've built several "free energy" DC-DC converters, just like this guy ;)

It's always flattering to get 105% when you aim for 90%... Burn a candle to Murphy, and... once the measurement bugs were sorted out, things went back to normal.

Here is how to fail at measuring power with multimeters:

- Multimeters measure **average** voltage and current
- However, power is **instantaneous**  \$v\times i\$
- You have ripple on voltage and current

For an efficiency measurement, we can average power over a time interval T:

\$P_{avg} = \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} vi \, dt\$

As you no doubt know, if v and i are both constant (ie, DC) then :

\$ \int vi = \int v \int i \$

This is what the guy in the video assumes. **However,** if both v and i have ripple, then this no longer holds.

This is the same as the apparent power versus RMS power in the AC realm. When voltage and current are not perfectly in phase, you need to account for \$ cos \phi \$. And if your sine wave looks like an epileptic noodle on crack because harmonics, sweep \$ cos \phi \$ under the rug and use a decent analyzer...

For the same reason, when you have "DC" voltages and currents with non-negligible AC ripple on top, then your multimeters will give perfectly valid average voltage and current reading, but the product will give a power that is completely bogus.

Let's consider a 5V LDO with a maximum output current of 1 amp, and decent protection. Let's connect this LDO's output to a big, fat MOSFET which shorts it out with a duty cycle of 50%.

When the MOSFET is ON, output voltage is 0V, short circuit current is 1 amp, and output power is 0V*1A=0W.

When the MOSFET is OFF, output voltage is 5V, current is 0A, and power is 0W too.

Multimeters would read an average output current and voltage of 0.5A and 2.5V, since our MOSFET shorts the output 50% of the time.

Therefore, 0W = 0.5A*2.5V = 1.25W

I will repeat: **Even an analog meter which is insensitive to spikes and RF noise will not make \$ \int vi \$ equal to \$ \int v \int i \$ if v and i have ripple.**

You can do pretty nifty stuff with scopes too. I've seen a guy get 200% efficiency because the scope sample rate was set too low. With about one sample per period of the signal to analyze... your precision aint that good.

Funny thing was, that guy was into "overunity" bull**** so when I suggested he kinda set up his scope to take more samples (which resulted in correct measurements, i.e. lower than 100% efficiency) then he went into a hissing fit and blew his top....

Comment: [Some people](http://www.overunity.com/7403/this-ltspice-simulation-model-will-blow-your-mind/) can't even be convinced with accurate plots, if they think you can apply sine wave RMS approximations to other waveforms.

Comment: +1 Yep, this is a very common mistake when a desired quantity (Power in this case) is an algebraic product of two variable/fluctating functions. Average of a product (P)  is not equal to the product of independently measured/averaged I and V. Hell, people are trying to make business on "magic water heaters" using "impulse power". There are even granted patents on this scam! Most so-called "cold fusion" experiments were victims of this brutal mistake. If you apply voltage pulses with duty cycle of 1%, one can come up with 1000% "efficiency" of such a  device.

Comment: When in doubt, listen for black helicopters coming to get you ;)

Answer (score 4):

The error is obvious: the idiot who made the video has the "output ammeter" connected directly between the input V+ and the output V+, which is a completely meaningless measurement, and has nothing whatsoever to do with the actual output power.

If the ammeter were instead connected in series with an actual load connected across the converter's output, then he'd get an actual output power measurement, which he could then compare to the input power measurement (which would then be much higher, of course).

---

You might ask, where is the 0.7A coming from, anyway? To answer that, we have to make some guesses about exactly what kind of DC-DC converter it is. The most obvious answer to me is that it is a buck converter with synchronous rectification, something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNDzI6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What's happening here is that the bogus ammeter is effectively applying the input voltage to the output of the converter, which completely breaks how the converter wants to operate.

As a result of trying to regulate the output voltage, the controller inside the converter pulses the lower transistor (M2) with a very short duty cycle. This causes the inductor to "charge up" with current *in the wrong direction* — i.e., in the direction of the red arrows.

The energy stored in the inductor then needs to go somewhere when M2 switches off. The only place it can go is through the upper transistor's body diode (D1), and through the ammeter, which completes the circuit.

Note that the input ammeter AM1 is only measuring current when M2 is switched on, and during that short interval, the current is the same as the current in AM2. But the low duty cycle means that the *average* current that AM1 sees is the 37 mA that the video shows.

If we assume that AM2 has 1 Ω of resistance on the selected scale, then it is dissipating about 0.7A<sup>2</sup> × 1Ω = 0.49W, which is close to the input power shown in the video. No "overunity" effect at all!

Comment: Ya but he says that the negative is already connected internally inside the converter, and so the only thing really to connect is the output positive to the input positive and the ammeter is there to show current flowing back to the source.

Comment: Maybe not obvious to the average youtuber, that the ammeter must be in series with the load. Voltage measurement needs a ground reference, but current measurement needs to be in series with the load.

Comment: @MarcStriebeck: Note that the ammeter is showing 0.7A flowing **away from the source**, not toward it! See my explanation above.

Comment: @DaveTweed by 'source' do you mean the wall adapter?  I don't think that's the case.  The video shows the current from the regulator output back to the input (unless he modified that output current meter to reverse the polarity internally).  I think he just increased the output voltage slightly above the input voltage to force current out and back to the input.  You can actually see the output voltage is 30mV higher.

Comment: @AngeloQ: Yes, on reviewing the video a second time, I see that the polarity of the ammeter is the other way around. Therefore, it must be a boost (or SEPIC) converter, and the current is circulating around the loop I drew in the other direction, but for much the same reason. It's still bogus to relate this current to anything having to do with "output power".

Comment: Agreed.  Ironic his channel is called 'debunkified'.

Comment: Hi, I get everything so far for the most part. For whatever it's worth the input current appears to be read on the negative side while the output is being read on the positive side and it does indeed appear that the output is simply being fed back to the input and the meters are not backwards as the negative of the input is on the negative of the meter and the positive of the output is on the positive of the meter and I don't see any negative numbers or currents.

Comment: @MarcStriebeck, that's true, the 'input' current is measured at the negative side, but the current from the wall adapter on the positive side should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Meters are imperfect and can be fooled. It's entirely possible for a meter to show you falsely high values of voltage and current under certain situations, so even if the guy isn't intentionally defrauding you he's just misusing his test equipment. Assuming the video isn't an outright scam, what could be happening is that the numbers on the meter represent spikes in the current, and the *average* current is much lower. Bottom line, you can't get more power out than you put in.

Comment: What about the type of DC-to-DC converters that do not use collapsing magnetic fields with voltage spikes or step-up transformers? For instance the ones that use just capacitors and diodes where two capacitors are connected in series to boost voltage while the other two are connected in parallel? Would those cause weird wave forms as well to mess up the accuracy of meters, analog or digital?

Comment: It depends on several of factors such as the sample rate of your test equipment and the assumptions you've made about the waveform you're measuring. Some of the other answers above explain this in more depth than I can, in particular peufeu's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't doubt that you would see the same results if you set up the same test.  The flaw however is that the 'output' current measurement is also part of the input current.

This is a simplified schematic of the circuit.  I1 is ~40mA, and I2 is ~690mA.  But I2 is feed back into the input AFTER the 'input' current measurement.  I1 is not the current into the regulator.  It's I1 + I2 = ~730mA.  The efficiency is actually about 690/730 = ~95% (it's not 1800%, but hey still not bad).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqkinb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The device is a boost converter and you can see the output voltage is 30mA higher than the input.  He adjusted the output voltage slightly above the input voltage to force current back to the input.

It's fun debunking things like this, but it's a shame that people (and companies) increasingly are trying to convince people overunity is possible.